# sphinx: add link to title (section) in external document that does not have a reference tag

Tags: django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using intersphinx to add links to Django's documentation. However, most of the sections that I'd like to point to do not have reference tags like this:

```
.. _reference_tag:

     Section Title
     =============
     ...
```

They are mostly just the titles:

```
     Section Title
     =============
     ....
```

How can I add references (links) to titles in external documents that do not have reference tags?

Comment: I don't think you can use intersphinx in this case. You probably have to use a external link that points to `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/...`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I end up doing...